# Compare previously defined time

Tags: python

I'm new to Python.

I want to use ***previously_defined_time*** variable, to compare current **datetime** value with the value from the last time this function was executed. How it can be done?

```
import datetime

if foo():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (now – priviously_defined_time) > 1000:
        ..
        some code
        ..
        priviously_defined_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: Is there any initial value for `priviously_defined_time`? I mean the first time you'll call the function there will be no "previous" time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the keyword `global`

```
import datetime
#define somewhere your  previously_defined_time 
previously_defined_time = 0

if foo():
    # use the word global to indicate that previously_defined_time is a global variable
    global previously_defined_time
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if (now – previously_defined_time) > 1000:
        # ..
        # some code
        # ..
        previously_defined_time = datetime.datetime.now()
```

Comment: If I have additional foo2() function, I am also need to use keyword "global" with previously_defined_time variable or it need to be writed once (in foo())?